# How do I write a select query in Laravel Eloquent with DISTINCT nested in COUNT?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I achieve this is Eloquent:

```
select count(distinct(SID)) from history where `Date` < '2020-08-19'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
History::distinct()->where('Date','<','2020-09-19')->count()
```

for choosing a specific column provide the column name inside the distinct function

```
distinct('SID')
```

if your Model is named History, i have no idea whats your model name is :)

Comment: Lol. What if what I want distinct on is not the key of the table? Is it then history::distinct('other_column')...?

Comment: yes and i edited the answer to match what you asking for

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = History::where('Date','<',''2020-09-19)->count();
```

**In model onetomany relation**
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships